# Pass temp data from MyAuthenticationHandler to MyAuthorizationFilterAttribute in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

When my authentication handler passes successfully (userId is taken from decrypted token) I want to add the userId somewhere to the current request object.

Later in the pipeline when the user is authenticated the authorization is executed and here I need the userId again because I have to disallow authenticated users manipulating data from other users having a certain userId.

What would be the best way to save temporarely the userId? Should I misuse the request.headers to add there the userId?

Comment: There is a `Properties` collection on `HttpRequestMessage` which you could use.

Comment: Thanks that should work. Never have seen the collection before ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmon Darrel...please don't re-invent the wheel ;)

The authentication handler outcome should be a ClaimsPrincipal (set it on HttpAuthenticationContext.Principal).

This way you make the user id available to an authorization filter - as well as ApiController.User.

Comment: Hello Dominick, knowing you are the security guru ;-) I am asking an easy question on your advise. If I would follow @Darrel`s advise my userId is ALSO available at my custom AuthorizationFilter and as well the UserController via Request.Properties etc... so what advantage has the usage of your ClaimsPrincipal really?

Comment: My AuthenticationHandler which is a DelegatingHandler has no HttpAuthenticationContext property. I can find the HttpAuthenticationContext class only in the http filters but thats too late in the pipeline. Ok I found it: Inside the handler.SendAsync I can do: request.GetRequestContext(); there is the object with the Principal property. But  it has only a name (string) property. I have a userId (int)... A name is not unique at all. Thats confusing...

Comment: It's a simple architecture - someone (e.g. the handler) set the principal - the rest of the request "gets" it via a standard mechanism. e.g. it is passed into the authZ filter - it is available via ApiController.User, Request.RequestContext etc. Simply create a claims principal including a claim (e.g. ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) and set that on the RequestContext. The properties collection works as well of course. I am just sayin...

Comment: yes I understand your concern and its really about seperation of concerns here the ClaimsPrincipal is built for such things. Therefore you mentioned the reinvention. I just must think how my NameIdentinfier fits in here because I always have to use the userId which is an sql auto inc. If I have to go to the database in my auth handler or authorization filter to check things I always have to use  a integer id therefore the ClaimsPrinicipal seems useless to me.

Comment: Well - the add an extensions method to claims principal that gives you back the int.

Answer (score 0):

HttpRequestMesssage.Properties.  It is a dictionary designed for storing request scoped data.